# Advanced custom fields bootstrap slider active state

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, advanced-custom-fields

I have a slider built in *bootstrap* and using *Advanced Custom Field*s in *WordPress*, my data attribute when written in HTMl the `data-slide-to=""` would be 0, 1 ,2 ,3 and so on.

If i was to write this in HTML it works. now I have integrated it with *WordPress* *Advanced Custom Fields* and added php I can now inspect the code and see the data attribute having 0, 1, 2, 3 onward. however now i click on the div with this attribute and the slide wont change as it did written in HTML.

is there something in my code preventing this, why wont my slide change now if click on the div with a different `data-slide-to=""`?

For example in HTML if i click on the div with `data-slide-to="1"` then it shows the second slide.

however now written in PHP this in not working, can some one help me understand why?

**my code**

```
     <?php
$sliderImages = get_field('slider');
$count = 0;
?>
<section class="pb-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="carousel_03" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators tabs row">
                            <?php if (have_rows('slider')):
                            while (have_rows('slider')): the_row();
                            ?>
                            <li class="col-lg-12 col-sm-6 mb-2 <?php echo ($count ++) >= 1 ? '' : 'active'; ?> ">
                                <div data-target="#carousel_3" data-slide-to="<?php echo ($count ++); ?>" role="button"
                                     class="carousel-indicator p-3">
                                    <h4 class="mb-1"><?php the_sub_field('title', $post->ID)?></h4>
                                    <?php
                                    endwhile;
                                    endif;
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 mb-3">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <?php foreach ($sliderImages as $imgNumber => $image) : ?>
                            <div class="carousel-item<?php if ($imgNumber === 0) : ?> active<?php endif ?>">
                                <img src="<?= $image['image']['url'] ?>" alt="<?= $image['image']['alt'] ?>">
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel_03" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel_03" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Compare the output of your PHP code to the static HTML version that works, and figure out where there are any significant differences …?

Comment: I have done this, but your right. ill grab some coffee and try again. thanks. I think the way im displaying the data-slide-to is wrong. ill look into it

Comment: @misorude you were right, it helped and found the answer thanks man